# Problem with the palindromeRearranging task on CodeFights

Tags: c

This is the text of the task:

---

Given a string, find out if its characters can be rearranged to form a palindrome.

**Example**

For inputString = "aabb", the output should be
solution(inputString) = true.
We can rearrange "aabb" to make "abba", which is a palindrome.**

---

And I tried to do it like this:

```
bool solution(char * inputString) {
int n = strlen(inputString);
int i, j, br = 0, pom = 0;

for ( i=0 ; i<n-1 ; i++ )
    for ( j=i+1 ; j<n ; j++ )
        if ( inputString[i] < inputString[j] )
        {
            char pomocni = inputString[i];
            inputString[i] = inputString[j];
            inputString[j] = pomocni;
        }

if ( n%2 == 0 )
{
    for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
    {
        br = 0;
        for ( j=0 ; j<n ; j++ )
            if ( inputString[i] == inputString[j] )
                br++;
        if ( br%2 != 0 )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
else {
    for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
    {
        br = 0;
        for ( j=0 ; j<n ; j++ )
            if ( inputString[i] == inputString[j] )
                br++;
        if ( br%2 != 0 )
        {
            pom++;
        }
    }
    if ( pom > 1 )
        return false;
}
return true;
```

The sorting part is just something I tried later on, but it didn't help and it didn't change any of the outputs. The thing is, my code passed 18/20 tests and the 2 tests that weren't passed are hidden and I can't see them.

Does anyone see the problem in my code (once again, ignore the sorting part), and if so, please tell me how to make it work.

As you can see, I noticed that if the string has an even number of characters, it can form a palindrome if each character is repeated an even number of times. For the strings that have an odd number of characters, not every single character needs to be repeated an even number of times. There can be one case where it is an odd number and it would still be able to form a palindrome.

Comment: Just two failed tests? Those CodeFights testers probably wouldn't be able to test their way out of a wet paper bag. Have you tried your own tests? Try "aaa".

Comment: Pretty much all of the *visible* test are okay. The "aaa" test works well and gives a true output.

Comment: True? Let's see [clickety click](https://godbolt.org/z/hKa3noaWY).

Comment: Seems like I was looking at the expected output and not the real output... Thanks, I resolved my issue with your help by adding if ( inputString[i] != inputString[i-1]) before the for (j=...) in the else sector. Thank you very much!

Comment: `if ( inputString[i] != inputString[i-1])` is incorrect if `i == 0`

Comment: Yeah, I made a protection for that.